# Magento 2: Add BCC programmatically

Tags: magento2, email

I am using below code to add BCC:

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom('sales')
                ->addTo($copy_to)
                ->addBcc('test@test.com')
                ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
```

`->addBcc('test@test.com')` adds email ID to `TO` instead of adding it to `BCC`.

Comment: The code seems correct, can you try using core php code on root and send to bcc if that works, just for testing purpose? If it works, check how bcc is passed at vendor\magento\module-checkout\Helper\Data.php

Comment: The code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays of emails like

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom('sales')
            ->addTo([$copy_to,'test@test.com'])
            ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked code is fine, issue was with my SMTP configuration.